# Identify if the number is complex C++

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

How can I identify if the number is complex in C++?

Is there any built in function like this?:

```
isComplex(1)->false
```

Comment: Just check if the type is [`std::complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)?

Comment: Check for `.imag() != 0`

Comment: yes something like that

Comment: Mathematically `1` is complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is a strongly typed language, and the literal `1` is always an `int`.

The determination you ask about might be relevant when converting text... `isComplex("1")`, for that you can attempt streaming:

```
std::istringstream iss(some_text);
std::complex<double> my_complex;
char c;
if (iss >> my_complex &&  // conversion possible...
    !(iss >> c))          // no unconverted non-whitespace characters afterwards
    ...use my_complex...
else
    throw std::runtime_error("input was not a valid complex number");
```

---

Separately, if you're inside a template and not sure whether a type parameter is `std::complex`, you can test with e.g. [`std::is_same<T, std::is_complex<double>>::value`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same), for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

double get_real(double n) { return n; }

double get_real(const std::complex<double>& n) { return n.real(); }

template <typename T>
std::complex<double> f(T n)
{
    if (std::is_same<T, std::complex<double>>::value)
        return n * std::complex<double>{1, -1} + get_real(n);
    else
        return -n;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << f(std::complex<double>{10, 10}) << '\n';
    std::cout << f(10.0) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
(30,0)
(-10,0)
```

See the code [here](http://ideone.com/amjewP).

For more complicated functions, you may want to create separate overloads for e.g. `double` and `std::complex<double>`, and/or `float` and `std::complex<float>`, `long double` etc..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Couple you please clarify the second part? std::is_same<T, std::is_complex>::value

I mean like, if you are in template and checked if it is complex, and want to take the real part, can you do something like value[1]?

Comment: @Mike: answer updated with a complete example.  You could call `n.real()` but then you'd need to create separate functions for complex and non-complex types, either separate `f`s in my example or separate support functions (easier)... I'll illustrate.